# Не получается растянуть контейнер на всю ширину

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Как сделать так, чтобы все элементы были в контейнере, а 1 элемент был на всю ширину страницы, но контент в нём оставался в контейнере?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пример конкретной верстки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: gray
}
.wrapper {
  background: red;
}
.small {
height: 100px;
background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
content
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content small">
    another content
  </div>
</div>
```